# Why $m(B^n(0, r)) = c_nr^n$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

(Bear with me: I realize this is quite basic question, but I'm a little loss at  how to search for an answer). Anyway:

I came across a real analysis proof which uses a property that (as far as I can see) amounts to this:

Suppose $B^n(0, r)$ is a $n$-dimensional (open) ball (in $\mathbb{R}^n$) and $m$ is a (complete) measure.

Now $m(B^n(0, r))$ can be written as $c_nr^n$, $c_n$ being a constant dependent only on dimension $n$.

My "gut feeling" is that this follows from translation invariance of a measure (is this correct?), but the result isn't immediate to me.

Comment: If the only hypothesis on $m$ is that it is a complete measure, then this is not true.

Comment: Also, even if you have translation invariance, this result has nothing to do with it! Indeed, your claim is about balls centered at the origin.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez I think I disagree with your second statement. You want that it scales with the dimension in the indicated way, but this comes from a modulus function on the general linear group for the locally compact vector space, and it's going to be exactly a Haar measure that has the right property if it scales exactly as the op wants.

Comment: Sure! But getting there from plain translation invariant is non-trivial. That is my point.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez apologies, when you said "the result has nothing to do with it" I got confused. I'm guessing now that was a pedagogical comment.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed it does. The translation invariance makes it into a Haar measure, and it's easily verified that it holds for Lebesgue measure (standard integration),

$$\int_{B(0,r^n)}\,dV=r^n\int_{B(0,1)}dV'=c_nr^n$$

holds by change of coordinates, with $c_0$ being the Lebesgue measure of the unit ball, which we see by letting

$$\begin{cases} y_i=rx_i \\dy_i=rdx_i \\dV=r^ndV'\end{cases}$$

Comment: +1. It should be $c_n$ instead of $c_0$ in the first formula. Too short so I cannot edit myself ;)

Comment: Err, right. @_@

Comment: What do you mean by your last statement? Do you have a reference for this fact?

Comment: @DanZimm If you mean that Haar measure is unique up to a constant, that's a pretty standard fact. You can find it on Wikipedia even.

Comment: @AdamHughes oop, didn't realize that's what you were saying in that last statement (now deleted), my apologies